# ExtJs rowExpander plugin - automatically expand based on row data

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to accomplish something which sounds simple, but I'm not finding a solution.

I've got a grid in front of a buffered store and a rowExpander plugin.  Everything is working fine, but I'd like to have the expander default to open based on an attribute (in this case a simple boolean value) in the store.  Normally I'd loop through all the records initially, but since it's a buffered store, I don't have all of the records at first.

Is there something on the bufferedRenderer that I can hook into?

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

the below fiddle has the following code which will attempt to expand when replycount > 1

```
            prefetch: function (store, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {
            console.log('in prefetch')
            var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#testGrid')[0];
            var pluggy = grid.getPlugin('rowexpander')

            for (var i in records) {
                if (records[i].get('replycount') > 1) {
                    console.log(records[i].get('replycount') + ': is greater than 1...so expand');
                    var rIndex = store.indexOf(records[i]);
                    pluggy.toggleRow(rIndex, records[i]);
                } else {
                    //console.log(records[i].get('replycount') + ': is not greater than 1...so no expand');
                }
            }
        }
```

adding fiddle:  [link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20qh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `load` event of `ExtJS Store`. This event fires whenever records have been load.

```
load: function (store, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {
            var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#testGrid')[0];
            var pluggy = grid.getPlugin('rowexpander')
            for (var i in records) {
                if (records[i].get('replycount') > 1) {
                    console.log(records[i].get('replycount') + ': is greater than 1...so expand');
                    var rIndex = store.indexOf(records[i]);
                    pluggy.toggleRow(rIndex, records[i]);
                } else {
                    //console.log(records[i].get('replycount') + ': is not greater than 1...so no expand');
                }
            }
        }
```

Please refer this [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#event-prefetch). Hope this helps. [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20t0).

I have tried with different approach. You can write one column without `dataindex` and on `renderer` of that column you can expand the raw.

```
{
            sortable: false,
            //hidden : true,
            width : 0,
            hideable : false,
            renderer : function (v, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
                 Ext.defer(function(){
                    try{
                        var grid = view.up('grid');
                         var pluggy = grid.getPlugin('rowexpander');
                          if (record.get('replycount') > 1) {
                            pluggy.toggleRow(rowIndex, record);
                        } else {
                            //console.log(records[i].get('replycount') + ': is not greater than 1...so no expand');
                        }
                    }catch(e){}
                 },1000);
            }
        }
```

I have updated the same fiddle.

**Note:**  This is just a workaround.

Comment: I looked into prefetch, and thought I was on the right track, but from that function, I wasn't able to figure out how to signal the rowexpander to render for particular rows.

Comment: Thanks Ronak - I'll work on adding a fiddle demonstrating what I'm seeing, but a quick implementation of your example is giving me the impression that the row isn't added to the grid yet.  I'm getting following error from the toggleRow.  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'down' of null

Comment: Please share fiddle.

Comment: We've got a version which will open expanded now utilizing the prefetch, but it's not using toggleRow.  I need to have expandBody firing, which it's not using this implementation.  [fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20r6)

Comment: I have change my answer and it is working in fiddle. i have change the event from prefetch to load. sorry for wrong event answer.

Comment: I actually think you were in the right spot with the prefetch, the load doesn't get called on subsequent page events

Comment: Wow...nice, I don't know much about Ext.defer, will need to do some reading up on that!